# Wrong input autofill position on scroll (chrome)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am having some problem with the default auto fill of an input text in chrome browser.
It is moving when the page is scrolling in the bootstrap modal.
I would like that the auto fill text stays right below the input. or On the scroll, the autofill should disappear. Is there a way to do this?. This happens to me in Chrome browser.

I noticed this happens because of the overflow: auto property of bootstrap modal.

[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you provide us your code? Or even better go to https://jsfiddle.net/, input your code and give us a link so we can help you :)

Comment: Here is the same Js fiddle for my issue by David.
Open this in Chrome browser, adjust the window size and scroll vertically. the issue mentioned in question has been generated.
http://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/42ze5wgv/

Comment: You won´t be able to fix this. This is a native thing from Google Chrome. They give the autocomplete a fixed position. What i would suggest you is to hide the autocomplete when the user starts scrolling. See this issue here, it´s the same problem with a provided solution: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646805/wrong-input-autocompletion-position-on-scroll-chrome)

Comment: Thanks, @MarcelWasilewski, The problem has been solved by adding a js function on scroll and remove focus from the input field. Thanks, for your support. :-)